# How to override Log4J line number

Tags: java, parameters, log4j, overriding

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to be able to log out data using log4j. But, rather than the actual location of the log.info() statement, I would prefer the invoking function method name, line etc be displayed by log4j in the normal fields, not as log data.

Is it possible to override the data fields for a log event?

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void info(String msg)
    {
        Logger aLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();

        // -- Set the calling function location info here

        aLogger.info(msg);
     }
}


public class Bar
{
    public void test()
    {
        Foo.info("x");   // -- Want this line, file, class, method logged
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [diagnostic context](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html)? Not exactly what you're asking for but could solve your purpose.

Comment: I haven't but I will look into it.

Comment: if you want the `info()` method to do it. You could override it. Because that is not what `info()` normally does

Comment: @MukulGoel Override info in the logger?  I know its out of the norm.  I have an existing system that I'm trying to plug log4j into without changing all instances of the logging statements.  I have a home grown logger which uses static methods such as info, debug, etc.  In those methods I get the root logger and pass along the message.  The output shows the line, class, etc of the static method not the caller.  It looks like I have to bite the bullet and do the edits.

Comment: I was able to get this working by adding this to the properties file and extending the default logger with my overides

log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %-17c{2} (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I follow exactly what you are doing, but it sounds like AspectJ can help your issue.

If you were to create an aspect which wraps the calls to the logger's methods, you would be able to extract the caller's method/class and override any parameters that are being sent to the actual logger (using [ProceedingJoinPoint](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint.html)).

I'm not entirely sure where in Log4j you can specify your own line number, class info, etc, but I presume that something must be there somewhere.  Otherwise, you'll have to write your own implementation of a logger where you can specify that information.